# Qual a melhor tradução de "security" e "safety"

Tags: tradução-inglês

Como diferenciar:

*Security*: Se refere a segurança no sentido de acesso, ou seja, algo que é apenas acessado/utilizado por pessoa designadas.

*Safety*: Se refere a integridade seja física ou funcional de uma pessoa ou objeto.

Comment: Brincadeirinha: se "I saved myself" pode ser "safei-me", "safety" devia poder ser traduzido para "safadeza"!!

Comment: Nesses sentidos não acredito que haja palavras distintas no português, ambos são traduzidos como "segurança".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resposta simples:

*safety* - segurança

*security* - protecção

No entanto, muitas vezes são traduzidos como *segurança*.
Quando escrito em documentos de importância, como normas, requisitos e similares, é comum acrescentar a definição do que se entende por segurança e protecção. Desta forma tenta-se que os termos não sejam ambíguos.